# I tried to open my Laravel application which was developed 2yrs ago and when I register a user I see the following error

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, phpmyadmin, xampp

Trying to access array offset on value of type null

```
if ($previous['type'] === EmailLexer::S_BACKSLASH
```

Comment: Can you share anymore than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that the variable $previous, which you expect to be an array, is actually null. You can't use an array offset on a null. Given that you said it was developed 2 years ago, probably some library changed and has different return types. Check where you instantiate $previous or how it is assigned a value.

Comment: I added this and it worked " && $previous " Thanks very much

Comment: Will you please post an answer, how you used && previous and where. Because I also stucked here for 2 days. Help appreciated

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. This is how I did it:                                                                    if ($previous && $previous ['type'] === EmailLexer::S_BACKSLASH

Answer (score 0):

this error occur because of you set php version v7.4

**so downgrade your php version to v7.1 or v7.2**

otherwise update composer

```
composer update
```