# Trying to access array offset on value of type null - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Recently I changed my project to a new server and when I registered a user it throws an error while sending mail.
[image]

My code is this.

```
function test(Request $request) {
    $user = User::findOrFail(11);
    Mail::send('front.test', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
        $m->from('MYDOMAIN', 'Your Application');
        $m->to('abhishekvvvvv@gmail.com', 'Abhishek')->subject('Your Reminder!');
    }); 
}
```

**and the user with id 11**
[image]

and I have found something **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913634/i-tried-to-open-my-laravel-application-which-was-developed-2yrs-ago-and-when-i-r)** which I think can fix my problem. but I don't where I should use `&& $previous` in my code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _A little wierd_  `$user = User::findOrFail(11);` Are you sure that the User with an id of `11` actually exists. After a `findOrFail()` you really should check if it **Found** or **Failed** before assuming it found

Comment: @Riosant It seems that your issue concerns the version of php. You use `php -v` in terminal to check version. What is the current version of php?

Comment: I know it is the issue with my php version. But I can't downgrade below 7.3 due to server limitation.is there anything that can ignore or override this.

Comment: @Riosant did you try `php composer.phar update`? I think that your library must be updated.